# Filtering a UITableView with a UISearchController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to filter my searchbar in the UISearchController, but it's not filtering?

```
@interface TableViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults; // Filtered search results
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;

@end

@implementation TableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44.0);
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    self.objects = [@[@"iOS",@"is",@"kool"]mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}

- (void)searchThroughResults
{
    NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text];

    [self.searchResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self searchThroughResults];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return self.objects.count;
    } else {
        [self searchThroughResults];
        return self.searchResults.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the tableView not being filtered? I also posted it on: https://github.com/Kalson/iOS-Study/tree/master/SearchBar

Comment: try this my Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604959/how-to-search-tableview-content-in-ios/26607857#26607857

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to reload the UITableView after you changed your Array self.searchResults?
Try

```
- (void)searchThroughResults
{
    NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text];
    [self.searchResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: But 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is getting called after?

How do you ensure, that `tableView != self.tableView`?

Comment: with the if/else statement

Answer (score 0):

Although you have added UISearchBarDelegate, you have not added UISearchControllerDelegate or UISearchResultsUpdating delegates. So add these two in your angled brackets separated by commas at the top of your .m file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding breakpoints in the if statements where you check `if (tableView == self.tableView)` . If it is not passing that if statement then replace him with this one `if (![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {`. I've tried some simple project and it worked. Tell me if it helps you, if don't I will post some more code of my test project.